# Git push for sideffect only

Tags: git

`git push` allows passing options, which is what some CI runners (like Gitlab) rely on to parametrize / trigger execution of CI jobs.

So, in the view of the above: is there any way to run `git push` w/o modifying the history (I don't want to add dummy empty commits / modify comments in code etc.)? Essentially, what I want is to send options and to invoke the hook on the remote, if this can be achieved in the way other than running `git push`, I'm fine with it.

Comment: Sounds like an anti-pattern to me. These parameters should also be usable otherwise.

Comment: @DanielB you assume too much about the purpose of such an action. Did you think about, say, security implications of being able to do so, for example? I'm asking this question because I don't know how `git push` is actually implemented. I don't care really about what you think about how I should use it.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to run git push w/o modifying the history

No, there is not. The whole point of `git push` is to modify a branch.

That said, CI systems generally offer other hooks for triggering builds, such as a REST endpoint. For example, Gitlab allows [triggering a build via its REST API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).

Comment: Is this knowledge based on being familiar with implementation of Git, or just from reading documentation?

Comment: @wvxvw: It's based mostly on documentation, and some general knowledge of the implementation.